# How can I vertically center one element, instead of the whole group

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir

So I can vertically and horizontally center a group with the `vplace` environment from `memoir`.

```
\begin{vplace}[0.7]
    \begin{center}
        some text \\
        more text \\
        a third line of text
        \vspace{0.25in} \hrule \vspace{0.25in} 
        {\Huge LARGER TEXT }
        \vspace{0.25in} \hrule \vspace{0.25in} 
        some other text
    \end{center}
\end{vplace}
```

But because the elements aren't vertically balanced, `LARGER TEXT` isn't vertically centered on the page.

How can I center `LARGER TEXT` and have `some text \\ more text \\ a third line of text` and `some other text` move around it?

---

This is an example, of course, the difference is much more noticeable with the actual elements I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use here [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and the `current page` family of nodes extended by the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package to position elements at absolute locations inside a page:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,every node/.append style={inner sep=0pt}]
\node[font=\Huge] 
  (center)
  at (current page text area.center)
  {LARGER TEXT};
\node[above=of center,align=center]
  (above)  
  {some text \\
  more text \\
  a third line of text
  };
\node[below=of center,align=center]
  (below)  
  {Some other text};
\draw
  ([xshift=-0.5\textwidth]$ (above.south)!0.5!(center.north) $ ) -- ++(\textwidth,0pt)
  ([xshift=-0.5\textwidth]$ (below.north)!0.5!(center.south) $ ) -- ++(\textwidth,0pt);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Using the keys for the nodes with the `positioning` library you can easily control the position to place the texts at the desired locations. For example, you can say `below=25pt of center` to locate the node `25pt` below the `center` node.

Comment: A good start, but the bottom line is closer to `LARGER TEXT` than it is to `some other text`. I haven't used the `\draw` syntax like that at all, so any help would be great.

Comment: @PressTilty Please see my updated answer.